# Show buttons in the li in mouseover and mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I make the next jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/46wyH/9/

please write text in input and press `enter` key. (and then press `enter` key again).

when the user mouse over the li (with the TAB), I want to show/hide two buttons (`x` and `v`), like in the next image:

[image]

I made two functions:

```
function showRemoveButton(element) {
    // I guess I need to create an element of span:
     var span = document.createElement('span');
     span.className = "closeButton";
     span.innerHTML = "x";
     element.appendChild(span);

     span = document.createElement('span');
     span.className = "closeButton";
     span.innerHTML = "v";
     element.appendChild(span);
}

function hideRemoveButton(element) {
    // remove the span element
    element.childNodes[1].parentNode.removeChild(element.childNodes[1].remove());
    element.childNodes[1].parentNode.removeChild(element.childNodes[1].remove());
}
```

I have two problems:

```
1) the `x` and `v` are not added in the right side of the li (like in the example).
```

I tried to do: `float: right;` but it doesn't work

```
2) when mouse out the li (the li that has TAB), the hideRemoveButton Throw an exception
```

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46wyH/11/) here's what i altered:

```
function showRemoveButton(element) {
    $(element).find("span").show();
}

function hideRemoveButton(element) {
    $(element).find("span").hide();
}
```

Also added this function with your code to add the buttons:

```
function addButtons(element) {
    // I guess I need to create an element of span:
     var span = document.createElement('span');
     span.className = "closeButton";
     span.innerHTML = "x";
     element.appendChild(span);

     span = document.createElement('span');
     span.className = "closeButton";
     span.innerHTML = "v";
     element.appendChild(span);
}
```